# How to re-route Azure Active Directory , authentication which ends up in Loop?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I have set up an authentication using AAd, I have set up the client id, application id and domain and added the services. But once I give in the credentials ,it loops into this page.

[image]

This is the configuration setting :

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
        {
            sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

        })
       .AddAzureAd(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
       .AddCookie();

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });


        services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("TestConnection")));

        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = ".TreeView.Session";
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3600);
        });

        services.AddTransient<IObjectRepositary, ObjectRepositary>();

        services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddHostedService<TicketingService>();

    }
```

I am passing in the app id, tentant id , call back url , domain information in app setting

Comment: What value is your CallBackPath? `/signin-oidc` ? It shouldn't be an URL. Also, are you using Identity?

Comment: Another thing, you're calling .AddMvc() twice

Comment: thank you. I have removed the second .AddMvc(). this is my callbackpath value in the appsetting.json -  "CallbackPath": "/.auth/login/aad/callback"

Comment: change your callback path to `/signin-oidc`

Comment: Thank you. I did as you suggested but no luck :(   I  also noticed  that I had set up the  Authentication / Authorization in app services , I had turned on app service authentication and was also using the app setting AD option at .net core.  When I turned off the App Service Authentication at App serice in Azure portal , After the login screen, I am now able to view the home screen.

Comment: But now I have another problem. When I logout of the app, it is redirecting me AAD logout page. After I clear out all the cookies, when I try a url, I am able to view the path. (it is not asking to login). I need to fix this. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To authenticate your webapp with Azure AD, you can use the [easy auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad) under App Service app. You do not need to make any changes to your code, just configure with express settings. If you want to **log the user out**, call `[your-domain]/.auth/logout`

If you don't want to use the authentication under App Service app, remember not to enable the authentication under App Service app. You can follow [this sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore/) to integrate Azure AD to your webapp.

The **SignOut method** also works fine:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult SignOut()
{
    var callbackUrl = Url.Action(nameof(SignedOut), "Account", values: null, protocol: Request.Scheme);
    return SignOut(
        new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = callbackUrl },
        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult SignedOut()
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        // Redirect to home page if the user is authenticated.
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
    }

    return View();
}
```